# XML as a default response for Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to create REST service which has to return by default application/XML as a response when no Accept header from the client is received. Unfortunately, Spring has as default JSON. How can I switch this default behaviour?

So far I have tried :

Adding this dependency helped to produce XML (but only with Accept header set  from client - so no default):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Trying to set the default for `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` in my @SpringBoot class

```
 @Bean
  ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean() {
    val myBean = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
    myBean.setDefaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    return myBean;
  }
```

resulted in error :

> Method viewResolver in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter required a single bean, but 2 were found

Trying to exclude it via:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean.class })
```

only gives another error:

> The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating your own `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` you could use a `ContentNegotiationConfigurer` to set up the default content type.

In your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, override the method `configureContentNegotiation()` and call the method `defaultContentType()` on the supplied `ContentNegotiationConfigurer`. That way, the auto configured `ContentNegotiationManager` will have that option set.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I looked for. Some note - WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated so I used implements WebMvcConfigurer in my SpringBootApplication instead.

Comment: Oh yeah I somehow assumed Spring 4.x/Spring Boot 1.x don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `RestTemplateBuilder` instead of `RestTemplate` solves this problem without any additional configuration.

This is hinted at in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58316756/1246547), although one may not realize immediately its importance:

> The auto-configured `RestTemplateBuilder` ensures that **sensible `HttpMessageConverters` are applied to `RestTemplate` instances**.